# Q: About reading data files using fscanf()

Tags: c

Am using Turbo C in a DOS emulator (Dosbox). In the following lines, I am trying to read integer and float data but only get the first (int) field. Have found much Q & A on the subject of reading files using fscanf() and, specifically, with space-delimited data but relevant info was scant or missing (mostly from the questions). Here is code demonstrating the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int index;
float rtime, volts;
char infilename[10]; 

int *pti;
float *ptx;
float *pty;
FILE *infp; 

void main(void)
{

infp = fopen("data1", "r"); 

pti = &index;
ptx = &rtime;
pty = &volts;

fscanf(infp, "%d  %6.3f   %6.3f",  &index, &rtime, &volts);

printf("%3d   %6.3f   %6.3f\n", index, rtime, volts);
}
```

Here is the first line from the data file:

```
37   261.100   0.996
```

printf gives the following output:

```
37   0.000   0.000
```

Any obvious goofs? thx

Comment: Try `fscanf(infp, "%d  %f   %f",  &index, &rtime, &volts);` instead of.

Comment: Don't use explicit field widths when the fields are delimited by whitespace.

Comment: The specification of `261.100` is actually `%7.3f` (the decimal point is also counted). And you do not need the `pti`, `ptx`, and `pty` variables.

Comment: Did you notice the compiler warning *'fscanf' : unknown type field character '.' in format specifier*? The `scanf` family is similar in some ways to the `printf` family, but different too.

Comment: Coding tip: Having trouble with `fscanf()` and family and _not_ checking the return value `fscanf()` is a waste of useful information.  Get in the habit of always checking Input function return values.  `if (fscanf(infp, "%d  %6.3f   %6.3f",  &index, &rtime, &volts) != 3) puts("add useful error handling message/code");`  Saves time.

Comment: `void` is NOT a valid return type from `main()`.  the return type should always be: `int`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level  2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) do not use a max length, max precision values,  just say `%f`.  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in the posted code, the global variable: `infilename[]` is not used.  Suggest removing that variable

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 10.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 4):

The format `%6.3f` is incorrect for `scanf()`. You probably want `%f`, or possibly `%7f`. You cannot specify the number of decimals in a `scanf()` format.

Comment: That  was what I needed. Much appreciated, all.